Prove that a set whose interior is connected is not necessarily connected itself?
I was unable to come with examples and my first attempt was wrong since I came up with a wrong proof. What counter examples might be given with $\mathbb R$ and the standard topology?
I thought of $(0,1) \cup \{2\}$ whose interior, namely $(0,1)$, is connected, but it is obviously not connected itself since the connected subset of $\mathbb R$ are exactly intervals.
Am I correct?

Please, use MathJax.

Your example is good.

Your counterexample is very good. And now I highly recommend going back to your proof and see which assertions in it are not true for your counterexample - it's a great way to get better at writing proofs!

Why do you have doubts?
